# Raspberry Pi 3 Cannot Find SD Card After First Boot

Tags: sd-card, retropie, pi-3

I'm a newbie when dealing with the Pi, as this is my first project with one.

I installed the latest version of Retropie on a 32 GB Samsung Micro SD card. The initial boot works as expected; the configuration menu comes up.

Last night I shutdown the Pi. When I turned it on this morning, the Pi cannot find the SD card. I wiped the SD card and remounted the image and low and behold, the Pi finds the SD card and starts the Retropie configuration again.

I shutdown the Pi when I was finished and turned it back on again. The SD cannot be found again.

How do I fix this so that I do not have to rewrite the image onto the SD card every time I restart the Pi?

Comment: How did you shutdown the Pi?

Comment: Since I have to have 50 rep to comment, I'll post like this. I shutdown the Pi by going to the Retropie menu and selecting shutdown. Was this the wrong way? I'm starting to think I just have a faulty SD Card.

Comment: My Pi 3 did the same thing with two different sd cards, but the third worked fine. It's probably a faulty/low quality card.